dot2texi issue on Overleaf: Conversion error for .dot file in a subfolder
I am trying to use the dot2texi package to generate dot graphs in LaTeX on Overleaf, but I encounter a problem when compiling a subfile.tex located in a subfolder. As a result, the graph is not generated in the subfile.
Here is my project structure:
.
├── main.tex
└── Subfolder
    └── subfile.tex

In the main.tex, I have the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\begin{document}

\begin{dot2tex}[file=maindotfile]
graph G {
node [shape="circle"]
A -- B -- C
}
\end{dot2tex}

\end{document}

In ./Subfolder/subfile.tex, I have similar code, but with a different output filename for the graph:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\begin{document}

\begin{dot2tex}[file=subdotfile]
graph G {
node [shape="circle"]
A -- B -- C
}
\end{dot2tex}

\end{document}

However, when I compile ./Subfolder/subfile.tex, I receive the following warnings:
Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of subdotfile.dot failed..
Package dot2texi Warning: Please convert subdotfile.dot manually.

This issue does not occur when I compile the main file. Here’s the output from pdfLaTeX when I compile ./Subfolder/subfile.tex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.8.9)  3 NOV 2024 16:17
entering extended mode
...
Opening dot2tex stream subdotfile.dot
runsystem(dot2tex --figonly -ftikz -o subdotfile.tex subdotfile.dot)...executed.
Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of subdotfile.dot failed..
Package dot2texi Warning: Please convert subdotfile.dot manually.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!
